# Question about sending parameters from remote Android device to ROS

Tags: rosbridge, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm developing an APK to send a number of parameters (integers and floats) to a ROS application through rosbridge. However I'm stumped at how to proceed. The parameters are to be used by particular nodes to do some operations with images. My question is, is it possible to send those parameters directly to the node or do I have to publish those parameters in an intermediary topic to then subscribe the nodes I already have to the appropriate parameter topics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283895/question-about-sending-parameters-from-remote-android-device-to-ros/) by [JKaiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/33362/jkaiser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-02-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a few options:

- You can use the [ROS parameter server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server) with the rosbridge according to [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosapi). The parameter server is more for setting parameters that do not change during the operation of the nodes.
- If you need the parameters to constantly change throughout operation then publishing a custom message with all your parameters in it should work. Or publishing multiple primitive types (ints, floats) to various subtopics such as `/image_params/width` and `/image_params/height` could work if the rosbridge doesn't allow custom messages.
- I would suggest [dynamic reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure), but I'm not sure if rosbridge supports it

---

Originally posted by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) with karma: 253 on 2018-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JKaiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/33362/jkaiser/) on 2018-08-09**:
The second option was the one I used and it worked fine. Thanks for your help IanCol

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-08-16**:
For the third option, see [Changing dynamic_reconfigure parameters using rosbridge](https://answers.ros.org/question/289904/changing-dynamic_reconfigure-parameters-using-rosbridge/)